# Properly getting string values from DataRow at specific column

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I am trying to get a value from a `DataRow` in a specific column in a `DataTable`. It should return values like "abc12345", but instead returns "ListViewSubItem: {abc12345}", according to the debugger. Why is this?

```
foreach (DataRow row in itemsTable.Rows)
{
    // the required data is in the first column of the DataTable

    // both of the following have been tried:
    string myValue = row[0].ToString();
    string myValue = row.Field<string>(0);
}
```

Comment: How did you define the column?  You are casting the column type to a string so depending on the column definition in the table you will get different responses.

Comment: @jdweng that was it! I forgot to set the type when defining the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. It should be `string myValue = row[columnIndex].Text;` and you are trying to get the value of the first column. You can use `row["columnName"]` also .

Note: I have used `Text` property.